How to create a pie chart with a hole (doughnut chart) in MPAndroidChart with ( optional ) different slice thickness
I am trying to make a pie / doughnut chart with varying thickness in MPAndroid chat, like so

I have to create the slices wit rounded corners and elevated shadows. I know that I need to extended PieChartRenderer and create a custom renderer.
I have tried to override the drawDataSet, loop through the IPieDataSet dataSet draw the slices with canvas.drawArc but I am not familiar with customviews and do not have much relevant code to post, and I do not want to post any AI generated code. I am at a loss here. What can I try?
Edit: Variable thickness not needed, I am able to create a shadow using a paint property paint.setShadowLayer(rad,dx,dy,color). I guess if many entires are present the chart will look ridiculous, if a min thickness is present that will be awesome, for now just need the slices with Rounded Corners like the image. and please comment as much as possible as I want to understand how canvas drawing works. setDrawSlicesUnderHole() setHoleRadius() may be used to make the hole. I would prefer that you don't.
